# Magick.NET check if two images are completely identical

Tags: c#, .net, imagemagick, magick.net

Which error metric in Magick is appropriate for checking if two images are completely identical, i.e. both in size and pixel content?

Something like:

```
return Math.Abs(img1.Compare(img2, ErrorMetric.Absolute)) < double.Epsilon;
```

Comment: Could hash both, compare hash?

Comment: Could using a base64 work? `img1.ToBase64(MagickFormat.Bmp).Equals(img2.ToBase64(MagickFormat.Bmp))`. They would however, have to be in the same format before testing.